# AWS Web Identity Federation, using dynamic roles for different users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Following articles on AWS Web Identity Federation I am a bit confused as to how can I ensure that each user who executes the **AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity** call **can assume a different role**?  Is that even possible?

The following are the steps ([ref.](http://jayendrapatil.com/iam-role-identity-providers-federation/)):

```
1. Mobile or Web Application needs to be configured with the IdP which gives each application a unique ID or client ID (also called audience)
2. Create an Identity Provider entity for OIDC compatible IdP in IAM.
3. Create IAM role and define the
    1. Trust policy –  specify the IdP (like Amazon) as the Principal (the trusted entity), and include a Condition that matches the IdP assigned app ID
    2. Permission policy – specify the permissions the application can assume
4. Application calls the sign-in interface for the IdP to login
5. IdP authenticates the user and returns an authentication token (OAuth access token or OIDC ID token) with information about the user to the application
6. Application then makes an unsigned call to the STS service with the **AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity** action to request temporary security credentials.
7. Application passes the IdP’s authentication token along with the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) for the IAM role created for that IdP.
8. AWS verifies that the token is trusted and valid and if so, returns temporary security credentials (access key, secret access key, session token, expiry time) to the application that have the permissions for the role that you name in the request.
9. STS response also includes metadata about the user from the IdP, such as the unique user ID that the IdP associates with the user.
10. Using the Temporary credentials, the application makes signed requests to AWS
11. User ID information from the identity provider can distinguish users in the app for e.g., objects can be put into S3 folders that include the user ID as prefixes or suffixes. This lets you create access control policies that lock the folder so only the user with that ID can access it.
12. Application can cache the temporary security credentials and refresh them before their expiry accordingly. Temporary credentials, by default, are good for an hour.
```

So from the above, in step 11, I can add dynamic [resource policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html) to resources to allow for user specific access, e.g. for S3.  Although what happens for resources which **don't support resource policies**?

E.g. how can I ensure that one user logging in using Google for example, gets Write access (WriteRole) to DynamoDB whereas another using logging in using the same Google IdP only gets Read access (ReadRole) to DynamoDB?

Any help will be appreciated.